# Vuex Action - Returning Axios Promise

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I am having some difficulty using a promise returned by axios in two places. I want to use `.then()` inside of my Vuex action to commit a change to my state, return the axios promise and use `.then()` again inside my component to update the UI. The issue I have encountered is that the promise response is undefined inside my component.

```
// component
methods: {
  getUser(userId) {
    this.$store.dispatch('GET_USER', userId)
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response); // undefined
      });
  }
}

// vuex
actions: {
  GET_USER: ({commit}, userId) => {
    return api.getUserById(userId)
      .then(({data}) => {
        commit('ADD_USER', data);
      });
  }
}

// api service
getUserById(userId) {
  return axios.get('/api/users/' + userId);
}
```

If I remove the use of `.then()` inside my Vuex action, `response` becomes the object from my api, but I'd like to have a promise in my component so that i can `catch` errors.

```
// component
methods: {
  getUser(userId) {
    this.$store.dispatch('GET_USER', userId)
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response); // no longer undefined
      });
  }
}

// vuex
actions: {
  GET_USER: ({commit}, userId) => {
    return api.getUserById(userId); // removed 'then' method
  }
}
```

What is wrong in the first code block?
Thanks.

Comment: In the first block, your `then` doesn't return anything (therefore returns `undefined`)

Comment: @Vivick Returning `data` from inside the first `then` worked. Thank you. You're welcome to write an answer so you can earn rep.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first block, your `then` doesn't return anything : therefore it returns `undefined`. Returning the resolved value should fix this issue.

Comment: I now have another issue. Chaining `.catch(response => {})` gives me `TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    at JSON.stringify`...

Comment: This would be a separate problem and feels like a problem in axios' deserialization

Answer (score 0):

You have to search, mapGetters, mapActions  and you have to check async function

for example

if you request to api you can do this.

```
//api.js

import axios from 'axios'
export aync function getuser() {
  ... 
  ...
  const data = await axios.get(url,{params:{....}})
  return data
}
//component
import {getuser} from '@/app.js'
import {mapAction} from 'vuex'
  data() {
  return {
    data:null
  }
}
methods: {
..mapAction('getUserAction')
  async getUserMethod () {
    this.data = await getuser()
    this.getUserAction(this.data)
  }
}



//store.js
actions: {

getUserAction () {
  // your actions..
  }
}
```